# how to get student's 2nd highest marks from a 2d array by using for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, multidimensional-array

Interviewer asked me to write code to find

**2nd highest marks of a student in java by using 2d array only and through for loop.**

```
String[][] arr = new String[][]{
                {"New Delhi", "5000"}, 
                {"Chennai", "4300"}, 
                {"Goa", "2940"}, 
                {"New Delhi", "2003"}, 
                {"Kolkata", "8904"}, 
                {"Kerala", "8972"}, 
                {"New Delhi", "8922"}, 
                {"Chennai", "8217"}, 
                {"New Delhi", "2462"}, 
                {"Kolkata", "5564"}, 
                {"Kerala", "9406"}};
```

i know how to find through sql query and through collection but i want through **2d array only nd by for loop.**

Looking for a simple and understandable  answer.

If anyone can help me out in this.

Comment: Can you show us the structure of the 2D array along with any code you have already tried?

Comment: We don't do your homework

Comment: Well good luck trying something!

Comment: //this is the structure of 2d array...i don't have a code yet because i havent tried yet through 2d array nd m not getting any solution

Comment: Don't put code in a comment. [Edit] your question if you want to add some code.

Comment: negative marking is fine but is there anyone who can help me out in this....structure is already mentioned above and answer is required.

Answer (score 0):

1. Load the marks into a separate array with the marks being turned into integers using parseInt.
2. The loop will be made to organize the marks from lowest to highest, get the highest index and subtract 1 from it.